# Simple parslet parser for comma-delimited list does not work

Tags: ruby, parslet

Why does the following Parslet parser not work for parsing comma-delimited lists? When I parse, it gets stuck and does not provide an error message:

```
class TestParser < Parslet::Parser

  rule(:name) { match['a-z'].repeat >> str(',').maybe }
  rule(:names) { name.repeat }

  root(:names)

end

TestParser.new.parse_with_debug('tom,samantha,ricardo')  # hangs here
```

I am aware of "[Parslet word until delimeter present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125235/parslet-word-until-delimeter-present)", and I know how to parse the list in other ways, but I don't understand *why* the above does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Explanation:*

An infinite loops mean you have a rule in your parser that you are looping over, but it can match against an empty string. If it consumed anything, you wouldn't get an infinite loop.

In your case: `Repeat` defaults to `Repeat(0)` which can match zero characters.  The `Maybe` makes the comma optional, so `name` can match without consuming anything, so it does...  Repeatedly.

*Solution:*

- Make `name` call `repeat(1)` instead.

*Diagnosis:*

Checkout my fork of Parslet that detects these infinite loops.

Its on github. ( https://github.com/NigelThorne/parslet )

My branch complains when it's going through a loop a second time, and it hasn't consumed anything since the last iteration.  (Only use this for development... as there is a check inside a time critical loop, so performs slower)

Comment: Thanks Nigel I was stuck here for some time :)